# How do we select model for causal inference?

Tags: inference, model-selection, causality, asymptotics, unbiased-estimator

I am reading Rubin's Causal Inference Sec 7.5 in context of completely randomized experiment.

1. It says performing linear regression will produce asymptotically unbiased estimate of causal effect, independent of whether model is misspecified.
2. However, in the later section, it says incorporating interaction between covariates(i.e. predictive feature) and treatment will yield higher precision.(This probably needs some prior knowledge.)

How do I select model in this case to infer causal effect? I have a bunch of linear models. The estimation of causal effect is asymptotically consistent and consistency is independent of misspecification. I cannot tell why 2 is necessary from 1. I would see that using other models should not asymptotically increasing my precision by 1 alone if residuals do not decrease. However, I could run into overfitting by introducing too many interactions.

How do I resolve my conflicting thoughts on 1 and 2 here? 1 says there is no need for interaction. I think 2 has a premise which is decreasing of residuals boost precision.

Comment: This is described in full by [Lin (2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/12-AOAS583) and [Negi & Wooldridge (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1080/07474938.2020.1824732) if you want to read more about this.

Comment: @Noah Thanks a lot for references. I will check them later today once I finish reading Rubin's Chapter 7.